Flink: Unable to do window aggregation after interval join
Flink version - 1.17, I'm trying to run the queries using SQL.
I have 2 continuous streams (orders and transactions) where I need to join both the streams (interval-join) and compute some aggregation metrics at fixed intervals(window aggregation).
I could get multiple records for an order_id where I'll need to pick the latest one. (I'm not quite sure if U should be using window tvf here, for a given if I'll not be having too many records anyways.)
create view orders_dedup as select order_id, order_status, order_ts  from (
  select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY order_ts DESC) as rn from orders_kafka 
) where rn=1;

create view txns_dedup as select order_id, payment_method_type, gateway, txn_ts  from (
  select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY txn_ts DESC) as rn from transaction_details_kafka 
) where rn=1;

create view orders_joined as SELECT L.order_id as order_id, R.payment_method_type, L.order_status,
  L.window_start as join_window_start, L.window_end as join_window_end, L.window_time rowtime
  FROM (
     SELECT * FROM TABLE(TUMBLE(TABLE orders_dedup, DESCRIPTOR(order_ts), INTERVAL '5' MINUTES))
  ) L
  INNER JOIN (
     SELECT * FROM TABLE(TUMBLE(TABLE txns_dedup, DESCRIPTOR(txn_ts), INTERVAL '5' MINUTES))
  ) R
  ON L.order_id = R.order_id AND L.window_start >= R.window_start - INTERVAL '15' MINUTES AND L.window_end <= R.window_end + INTERVAL '15' MINUTES;

It was working fine till here but when i'm not able to get fixed window aggregated metrics from the joined table.
select join_window_start, join_window_end, payment_method_type, 
count(distinct case when order_status='SUCCESS' then order_id else null end) successful_orders, count(distinct order_id) total_orders
from orders_joined
group by join_window_start, join_window_end, payment_method_type;

select join_window_start, join_window_end, payment_method_type, 
count(distinct case when order_status='SUCCESS' then order_id else null end) successful_orders, count(distinct order_id) total_orders
from orders_joined
group by join_window_start, join_window_end, payment_method_type;

Running above query emits results continuously but I only need final result at the end of window so I tried applying window aggregation which resulted in org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: The window function requires the timecol is a time attribute type, but is TIMESTAMP(3). attaching screenshot here
When I describe the orders_joined view, I could see the data type to be ROWTIME which should have worked.
Please kindly help me out.
Also I'm just strarted trying out flink so if there are is any better way to approach this please let me know. Thanks in advance.
